# Create page of sections (custom post type) - Admin - Wordpress (screenshot)

Tags: wordpress, themes, admin, custom-post-type

I have a couple of questions in regards to how I could approach a feature for a theme I'm developing.

I want to offer the ability to build pages from 'sections'.

I've made a custom post type called 'sections'. Imagine these consist of gallery's, text, large images etc.

When creating a page, I'd like to offer the admin a way of building that page from the 'sections'. Also be able to reorder the 'sections'.

I've made a rough mock up of create Page admin area (see below). The dropdown list contains all the 'sections' created. When selecting one, the 'section' gets added to the list below (boxes with the X on them). The list should be sortable by drag and drop. The result is a page made of those 'sections' in the desired order.

[image: Wordpress Admin Mock up]

I've got the post type done. I'm a little stuck as to how I'd create the functionality I desire.

Can Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) do this kind of thing?

Where would you start with this task?

Before I get results linking to Google searches, I've have been researching this but it's tough to know exactly what to search for without getting hundreds of posts relating to `creating custom post types`.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced custom fields can do this with the 'Repeater Field' extension.

You would create the repeater field 'Page Sections' then loop through this to get each sub field section utem (an added section.)

```
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('page_sections') ):

// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('page_sections') ) : the_row();

    // display a sub field value
    the_sub_field('page_sections_item');

endwhile;

else :

// no rows found

endif;
```

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: Ok great. Seems like a good place to start. I was having a bit of a creative block. Cheers.